# Webpack file-loader duplicating public directory

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

I am using Webpack to output files into a dist folder.

The directory structure is like so:
`client/public/dist`

inside which `bundle.js` and `styles.css` sit.

My file-loader setup is:

```
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  options: {
    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
  }
}
```

However what this is doing is putting my images inside another public directory like this:

`client/public/dist/public/images`

I'd prefer this:

`client/public/dist/images`

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    options: {
       name: '/images/[name].[ext]'
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @hpjm only works if all your files are in a flat directory.

To include subdirectory support:

```
  {
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
      outputPath: './',
      publicPath: '/',
    },
  }
```